# Hbase can't get master address from zookeeper - even though zkcli shows hbase directories

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

We have been repeatedly running into issues with zookeeper and hbase interworking.  The typical error is:

```
hbase(main):001:0> list
TABLE                                                                                                                   

ERROR: Can't get master address from ZooKeeper; znode data == null
```

We have checked that the nodes exist in zookeeper using the hbase zkcli ls command:

```
[zk: localhost.localdomain:2181(CONNECTED) 1] ls /hbase
[meta-region-server, backup-masters, table, draining, region-in-transition, table-lock, running, namespace, hbaseid, online-snapshot, replication, splitWAL, recovering-regions, rs]
```

In particular let us look at /hbase/hbaseid:

```
[zk: localhost.localdomain:2181(CONNECTED) 5] ls /hbase/hbaseid
[]
cZxid = 0x89
ctime = Mon May 12 01:42:49 PDT 2014
mZxid = 0x11dc
mtime = Tue Jul 01 17:51:13 PDT 2014
pZxid = 0x89
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 5
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x0
dataLength = 67
numChildren = 0
```

From my limited understanding of zookeeper/hbase interaction that seems healthy.  But are there are znodes/features to check?  Any other diagnostics or repair method hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

stop zookeeper and hbase.
Delete all contents from zookeeper dir.
start zookeeper and hbase again. it will solve your problem.